# Add same values in two different tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables 'order' & 'new-order', i need to add same values in both these table by using a single line of code.

My code is as follows:-

/**To add value in first Table**/

> mysql_query("insert into `order` (display, project, keyword) values
>   ('$cname','$pro','$kwrd')");

/**To add same value in second Table**/

> mysql_query("insert into`neworder`(display, project, keyword)
>   values('$cname','$pro','$kwrd')");

Now can i use some thing like this:-

> mysql_query("insert into `order` && `neworder` (display, project,
>   keyword)  values ('$cname','$pro','$kwrd')");

and if not then what should be the correct one.

Comment: Triggers The better option

Answer (score 2):

You can read more about it from the [MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html).  In short, you cannot insert into multiple tables at once.  This leaves you with three options:

1. Multiple `INSERT` statements
2. Triggers
3. Stored Procedures